# BitTorrent Peer wire protocol (TCP)

Tags: binary, bittorrent

How are the messages encoded or sent/received by peers?

If there is a message

> ```
> have: <len=0005><id=4><piece index>
> ```

How is this sent(in binary,how is it translated to binary?) and received?

Is there a specific order in which the messages are sent to peers?

I have read the specification but it leaves me with questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to declaring the `have` message [the specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) says:

> All of the remaining messages in the protocol take the form of <length prefix><message ID><payload>. The length prefix is a four byte big-endian value. The message ID is a single decimal byte. The payload is message dependent.

You've got the binary format for length and id right there. The 'piece index' part is this message's specific payload. It should be four bytes long since the message has a fixed size of 5 bytes and 1 byte went to the message ID (viewing other messages with the same format should give you a clue).

Comment: "viewing other messages with the same format should give you a clue". That's my issue :). Also what is e.g. <len=0005> or <len=0001>? if a message is like this <len=0005><id=4><piece index>  then the values between the  < > are replaced with there binary representation?

Comment: Assuming the piece index is 7 (why not?), the entire message would be: 0x000000050400000007.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer the ordering question.

In general, you can send any message at any time. But there are some messages which have special rules. The BITFIELD message has to be sent out early for instance. Most clients send PIECEs back in the order they were REQUESTed, but I don't think that is a requirement if memory serves.

In general the messages are of two types. One kind are control-oriented messages telling peers about general status (HAVE messages falls into this group). The other kind are data-oriented messages that actually transfers the file and requests new data from the peer. These message types are "interleaved" and one of the reasons you send PIECE messages no larger than 16 kilobytes is to make sure control messages can be interleaved in between. A trick is that when a PIECE message has been sent, then send all control-oriented messages by priority before the next PIECE message. That way, you quickly tell the other party of your intent.

There is also a "bug" in the original protocol which is solved by the FAST extension. It effectively make each REQUEST result in either a PIECE message or a REJECT-REQUEST message. This is another example of an ordering. If you get a REJECT-REQUEST message for something you never REQUESTED you disconnect the peer.

Comment: Thanks. How do people discover these things as the documentation is scarce?

Comment: Well, you implement a couple of BitTorrent clients for fun :) (I have two, one in Erlang and one in Haskell). The spec is scarce, but you will find that there is often only a single sensible thing to do when you begin implementing the client. The only thing I had to ask was "When you choke a peer, do you delete your local queue of REQUEST messages?". The answer to that one was yes and it relates to the "bug" i mentioned.

Comment: I have read your post comparing the 2 languages for the clients. You have the only worthy torrent client in Erlang. nice :) Well, in terms of the sensible thing, yeah I guess, but the problem Im facing now is implementing the protocol correctly. Its not so clear from the docs.Thanks for the above tip ;)

Comment: Well, it is not a simple protocol like HTTP. You can get a basic (non-conformant) HTTP client up and running in a couple of hours easily. That is not true with BitTorrent. It is a quite complex protocol and there are a large number of small twists you will encounter implementing it. But the quirkiness is also what makes the protocol interesting and fun.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but I wrote a few Node.js script that help understanding the Bittorrent protocol and should be helpful to anyone looking to understand the protocol and stumbles upon this question.

Here's the main script:
https://github.com/liveduo/bittorrent-scripts/blob/main/3-connect-node.js

You can run it locally easily and it doesn't even need an `npm install` as it has no external dependencies.

To get started you only need a torrent (ie. magnet id) and a node that has the torrent (ie. node ip address and port). In the [repository](https://github.com/LiveDuo/bittorrent-scripts) there's are more scripts to get nodes that own a torrent.

If you need some more help to get everything working I wrote on a guide [here](https://www.tzionis.com/bittorrent-protocol-in-25-minutes) that has explanations and embedded scripts you can run right on the website.